# Android Studio - Error:Connection timed out

Tags: android-studio

There's not configured nor running VPN, proxy, and/or anything else like that; Also *the No proxy* option is checked but I always get following error while syncing!

> Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy,
>   please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

**Note:** I'm using *Android Studio 2.1 Preview 4* and *Gradle 2.12*

Comment: Check IDE and Gradle settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who faced this problem, you must use `gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyHost -Dhttps.proxyPort=proxyPort -Dhttps.proxyUser=proxyUser -Dhttps.proxyPassword=proxyPasswor` command.

Thanks to @beeender at [GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2523#issuecomment-203881124).